# How String data is converted for SVM machine learning algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I have a dataset i.e.

```html
<table>
<tr><td>TEXT</td><td>TYPE</td></tr>
<tr><td>100% free cashback </td><td>spam</td></tr>
<tr><td>hello how are you </td><td>ham</td></tr>
<tr><td>click on this link to get free sms plan</td><td>spam</td></tr></table>
```

I want to know how the SVM machine learning algorithm convert this text column to plot on a graph so that it can infer a line which separates spam from ham.

I know that spam and ham can be converted to 0,1 respectively. But how to convert this text column to numeric values ??

Note: I want the procedure. I want to do it manually using pen and paper, not code using some python library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so that we are on the same page:
You are looking for a procedure on how to solve Spam Vs. Ham email classification using pen and paper.

To start with the basics, the text data cannot be sent directly to the model, 
1. we need to do data cleaning so that we extract multiple traits/features to in a matrix form ( 1 row = 1 email, 1 column = 1 feature) a feature/trait can be a word on any deep embeddings(Doc2Vec) of the email. 
2. In the same way, we also create a target data which is (1 row saying 1 if spam and 0 if Ham email)
Once you have both the data, you can solve the SVM algorithm by hand with the assumption that all the columns are different axis in the N-dimensional data plane.